# Triggering click event on datetimepicker close button via class doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

i am using jquery datetimepicker [addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

When the user selected the right datetime in the datetime div and pushes the "done"-button (with class ".ui-datepicker-close").

```
<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all" data-handler="hide" data-event="click">Done</button>
```

I want to use a click event on this buttons class to do some stuff.

i tried something like this:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-close").click(function () {
//do something
}
```

but this doesn't work.

Any guess?

Answer (score 0):

Have you exactly tried this:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-close").click(function () {
    //do something
}//<-- missing closing ); for the click() method
```

or the correct version:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-close").click(function(){
   //dome something
}); //<-- close the click() method
```

**EDIT**

First of all -

> To use this plugin you must include **jQuery (1.6+)** and jQuery UI with datepicker (and optionally slider).

I've checked out the addon you are using, so it's based on the standard jQuery UI Datepicker, which offers a great option `onClose:` , which you can use :) [Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose)

Here is the correct way to trigger a function on close

```
$("#datepicker").datetimepicker({
    onClose: function(){
        alert("You closed me!");
    },
});
```

**[Here is a working example in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sazgwat0/4/)**

Comment: i tried the correct version (with closed click method):


     `$(".ui-datepicker-close").click(function(){
   //do something
});`

Comment: Ok, any errors in your console? It would be really helpful if you could add a fiddle as an example. [Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktdnqscv/8/). I try to do some statements when the button with class .ui-datepicker-close is clicked

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work because you use `$("#datepicker").datetimepicker({` instead of `$("#datepicker").datepicker({`
But thanks für the hint with onClose! that will help me a lot!

Comment: using `datetimepicker` instead of `datepicker` wasn't the issue, take a look in the dev tools console next time ;) just the ressources I was loading (js and css for datetimepicker plugin) were not available anymore. I've updated my fiddle, it should work now ;)